# Can't install IMDbPY on windows

Tags: python, python-c-api, imdbpy

I'm having trouble installing IMDbPY on my windows computer. I think there is something wrong with my c compiler, because when I try to install it with easy_install or pip it gives me an error along these lines:

> C:>easy_install IMDbPY Searching for IMDbPY Best match: IMDbPY 4.9
>   Adding IMDbPY 4.9 to easy-install.pth file
>
> Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages Processing dependencies for IMDbPY
>   Searching for lxml Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/ Reading
>   http://codespeak.net/lxml Reading http://lxml.de/ Best match: lxml
>   3.1beta1 Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.1beta1.tar.gz
>   Processing lxml-3.1beta1.tar.gz Running lxml-3.1beta1\setup.py -q
>   bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\alex\appdata\loc
>   al\temp\easy_install-a8mii5\lxml-3.1beta1\egg-dist-tmp-0witf6 Building
>   lxml version 3.1.beta1. Building without Cython. ERROR: 'xslt-config'
>   is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
>   or batch file.
>
> ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
>
> Using build configuration of libxslt warning: no files found matching
>   'lxml.etree.c' under directory 'src\lxml' warning: no files found
>   matching 'lxml.objectify.c' under directory 'src\lxml' warning: no
>   files found matching 'lxml.etree.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
>   warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree_api.h' under directory
>   'src\lxml' warning: no files found matching 'etree_defs.h' under
>   directory 'src\lxml' warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under
>   directory 'src\lxml\tests' warning: no files found matching
>   'pubkey.asc' under directory 'doc' warning: no files found matching
>   'tagpython*.png' under directory 'doc' warning: no files found
>   matching 'Makefile' under directory 'doc' cc1.exe: error: unrecognized
>   command line option '-mno-cygwin' error: Setup script exited with
>   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Looking that error up, it seems people are usually recommended to install "python-dev", but as far as I can see that's just a linux package that I can't find for Windows.

When I try the Windows executable ([here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imdbpy/files/IMDbPY/4.7/IMDbPY-win32-py2.7-4.7.exe/download?use_mirror=iweb&download=)) it gives me what I assume is the same error, saying:

> Runtime Error! R6034 An application has made an attempt to load the C
>   runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support
>   team for more information.

So I'm getting pretty frustrated and thinking I'll just rig up something with BeautifulSoup, but if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be very grateful.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can install IMDbPY with pip because it depends on `lxml`, which in turn can't be compiled and installed because you don't have a working C compiler & the development file for `libxml2` and `libxslt`.

There are several solutions.

The first one is

- Install Visual C++ 2008 (Express version is ok, but not 2010 or 2012)
- Follow this [instruction](http://lxml.de/build.html#static-linking-on-windows) to install lxml, basically install `iconv, libxml2, libxslt, and zlib` from [here](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html), and then compile `lxml`
- Install IMDbPy using `pip` or `easy_install`

The second solution is

- Install lxml from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)
- Install IMDbPy using `pip` or `easy_install`

The third solution is

- Use [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) and install IMDbPY from [PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/imdbpy/)

The forth solution is

- Use the unofficial installer from the [homepage](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/downloads.html). Warning: this may not install all the necessary dependencies. You have encountered error with an older version of the installer, try using the latest one.

Comment: Thanks, will try one of the above tomorrow. However on your last suggestion, I did try with the newest installer and had the same problem. Also, it does seem to have installed something, I can import the module into Python, but when I try to run it I get a "IMDbDataAccessError".