# pip unable to Install svglib, libxml2 and libxslt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm hoping someone can help. I am trying to install svglib on my Raspberry Pi running Python 2.7.16
and pip version 18.1. When I try the following command:

```
sudo pip install svglib
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error: Please make sure the libxml2 and libxslt development packages are installed.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-b0APrc/lxml/
```

So I tried to install libxml2 and libxslt using following commands:

```
sudo pip install libxml2
sudo pip install libxslt
```

But trying to install those throws the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/libxml2/
```

Does anyone know how this can be fixed please?

I managed to succesfully instead svglib on my windows computer running Python 3.9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742865/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error%3A+Please+make+sure+the+libxml2+and+libxslt+development+packages+are+installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50002740/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782069/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+lxml+%22Raspberry+Pi%22

Comment: Those are system library files. You  should install them with system package manager like `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
```